# Install pyqt4 . Unable to locate package

Tags: apt, 16.04

In order to install Electrum Bitcoin Wallet, I need to install pyqt4. When I run the command `sudo apt-get install python-qt4` I get the error "Unable to locate package". How can I solve this?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Did you enable the `universe` repository (and then `update` your package list) first?

Answer (score 3):

First try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Then before you try installing the package again, I suggest looking into your sources list:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Go online and look at what Ubuntu default source list is supposed to look like and compare it to yours. If everything is fine, then go on and install the package. If you still get an error, reply back.

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer! By the way, you can improve your answer by describing what the apt commands do.

Comment: @alejoss I would clean first, then sudo the repositories, then do the updates and upgrades.  After all that check the sources list.

Comment: On Debian, I get "Error: 'universe' invalid" for universe, restricted, and multiverse